# X Axis not visible in Heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to make a heat map and the x axis is cut off - I attached a picture of the code here:

[image]

```
posts_matrix <- data.matrix(posts)
posts_heatmap <- heatmap(posts_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv = NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(1,10))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Remove or changing your margins should do the trick.

```
posts_matrix <- data.matrix(posts)
posts_heatmap <- heatmap(posts_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv = NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column")
```